# Prevent User from Getting Free Consumables by Re-Installing App

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an app which gives the user 4 free tokens to enable various functions. After the free tokens are used, I'd like the user to buy more through an in-app purchase (using version 3). How can I prevent the user from getting more free tokens by uninstalling and then re-installing the app? The app does have a back-end server that can maintain records, but I'd like to know the best practices for this scenario.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I dont know much about apps but I imagine everything local is deleted when the app is uninstalled. Some external data store with a unique phone ID(I assuem they all have one) would be the only way to go i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This largely depends on how thorough you want to be. Three options you have are:

- Storing data in your private store will result in it getting deleted
  when the user clears your data, or uninstalls your application, so is
  out.
- You could utilise the SD card (or internal storage, away from your
  applications private store), add a file to that which contains the
  config, which won't be deleted with an app deletion (but users may
  wise up to the file existing and realise what it does). This would be
  more fool proof.
- The best option of course it to sync with your backend server.

There are a couple of routes you can go down for syncing to a backend server. You could identify the user based on device id, and set a flag on your server that says that device has already redeemed it's entitlement.

You can access the device id via:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String androidId = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

This would be per-device, people could obtain more by using multiple devices. In this event, you could pair with their `Google Account`, allowing just one redemption per Google account that you would sync with your server.

For more information on how to uniquely identify a user on Android, see this Google article at the **Android Developer site** [here](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best practise for this scenario is to hold data on back end server. You need to record user to remote database then, every time you should get the info from back end service.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways.

1) Store some key-value pair on server, and whenever user start your app first time check/update with this.

2) Store some Key-value pair locally(you app space will be deleted), so try to write a file on sdcard on some location and with a suspicious name, which user should think is of a system file. encrypt it and it is done.

write a shared preferences, where you should add a boolen when user install ur app first time(from main activity). if this values is not available try checking with stored key-value pair you have written previously on server or on sdcard